# Properly match a Java string literal

Tags: java, regex, literals, string-literals

I am looking for a Regular expression to match string literals in Java source code.

Is it possible?

```
private String Foo = "A potato";
private String Bar = "A \"car\"";
```

My intent is to replace all strings within another string with something else. Using:

```
String A = "I went to the store to buy a \"coke\"";
String B = A.replaceAll(REGEX,"Pepsi");
```

Something like this.

Comment: Yes. Can you provide a source code snippet to explain better what you are after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. So what you want is to search, within a String, for a sequence of characters starting and ending with double-quotes?

```
    String bar = "A \"car\"";
    Pattern string = Pattern.compile("\".*?\"");
    Matcher matcher = string.matcher(bar);
    String result = matcher.replaceAll("\"bicycle\"");
```

Note the non-greedy `.*?` pattern.

Comment: And what if the String within the String also has quotes?

Comment: Yes. What then. How do you then know where it ends? In this case you have to see to it that quotes in the inner string are somehow escaped when constructing the outer string, deal with this in your replacement string, and then unescape the result again as and when required. One possible way of escaping quotes is, e.g., to double them.

Comment: If you double quotes to escape them, though, your regexp becomes tricky. A better one is probably to define another character to introduce the escape (e.g., & like in html), and then to escape all occurrences of that one as well.

Comment: This seems to have done what I intended. Many thanks.

Comment: Nitpick: it's a double quote, not an apostrophe.

Comment: One last question, what if the the original String is like : "A \"car\" and a \"boat\"" would it match against both strings? or would it match to both strings plus what's in the middle?

Answer (score 2):

this regex can handle double quotes as well (NOTE: perl extended syntax):

```
"
[^\\"]*
(?:
    (?:\\\\)*
    (?:
        \\
        "
        [^\\"]*
    )?
)*
"
```

it defines that each " has to have an odd amount of escaping \ before it

maybe it's possible to beautify this a bit, but it works in this form

Comment: This pattern comes VERY close to what I needed! However, what if the embedded string were to, say, contain a URL?
For example: "URL String: \"http:\/\/www.google.com\";", this expression then breaks, capturing only ";". (I've been scratching my head over this for hours)

Answer (score 1):

You can look at different parser generators for Java, and their regular expression for the StringLiteral grammar element.

Here is an [example from ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1152141644268/Java.g):

```
StringLiteral
    :  '"' ( EscapeSequence | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"'
    ;
```

Comment: I guess you would want to avoid catching `// "hello"`

Comment: I was always under the impression that most Java compilers pre-process comments out and only then look for everything else. But I might be wrong about this.

Comment: My problem with this answer is that I am not very confortable with grammars.

Comment: @Fork: My apologies. I assumed you were writing a parser for Java which is why you would care about the string literals....

Comment: No worries. I've tried that once, didn't go well :)

Comment: I've translate the grammar to a regex here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27225768/546188

Answer (score -1):

You don't say what tool you're using to do your finding (perl? sed? text editor ctrl-F etc etc). But a general regex would be:

```
\".*?\"
```

**Edit:** this is a quick & dirty answer, and doesn't cope with escaped quotes, comments etc

Comment: What about escaped quotes in the string?

Comment: I would imagine it's Java regex, considering the Java tag.

Comment: This also will match quotes in comments.  This shouldn't have false negatives, but it will definitely have false positives.

Comment: @glowcoder: I think the Java tag has to do with the fact that he wants to match text representing a String literal according to the Java spec, not that he wants to use Java to do the matching itself.

Comment: I will use Java to do the matching. Sorry for not being clear enough.